# Set an Initial Time String to an Input Element Using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have an `input` element of type `time` on my page which I save off the user time selection in the format which was given `12:22`. But I am having trouble loading the time `12:22` string back into the element on a return session.

How does one load the time, and show the time, in a type `input` element?

---

Element

```
<input type="time" id="Time1"/>
```

I've tried

```
$('#Time1').val = '3:22';
```

and

```
$('#Time1').value = '3:22';
```

with no luck.

---

My initial value in the config file (not set by the user) had a value of `3` and should be `03`. I am marking the answers related to the first problem of assignment and not the loading value which has to be `XX` not `X`.

Comment: Try `$('#Time1').val('12:22');` or `$('#Time1')[0].value = '12:22';`

Comment: I tried the hardcoded first you suggested, and got the time. Let me investigate the transport json with the time to see why it may be failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property does not exist in a jQuery object. Use the `val()` method:

```js
$('#Time1').val('12:22');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" id="Time1"/>
```

Comment: This resolved my initial problem which solved my issue and I am marking this as such. thx. The other post divined by second problem of trying to load `3:45` and not `03:45` which I didn't properly show initially....

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by the below code.

```js
function AssignTime() {
   
   var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("Time1").value = d.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'}).split(" ")[0];//time should be in 24 hrs format.
}
```

```html
Time: <input type="time" id="Time1">
<button onclick="AssignTime()">Assign</button>
```

Comment: This post divined my second problem ("time should be in 24 hrs format.
}" of trying to load `3:45` and not `03:45` which I didn't properly show initially (my bad)....I would like to mark this as the answer, but went with the other one.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan no problem bro. you can mark if u want :)